# Burn blue-ray (data disc), very unstable results with both nero and imgburn, suggestions?

Tags: burning, nero

I'm not sure if this is hw or software but the burner is new and should work. 
I have tested both imgburn and nero, so far I trashed one 50gb and one 25. They are not cheap. One succeeded with nero, but it said it failed. But it worked nonetheless.

Any suggestions for other software or settings I should use when burning BD data discs without trashing discs?

The link under is to the burner I just bought. 
http://www.sony-optiarc.eu/products/bluraydrivesdesktoppcs/bd5300s.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it can't even read it's own burnt dvd's. The thing broken. Pro tip for future, test burner with cheap dvd+r before using 50gb plates.